# Integral of area of ellipsoid

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

If we have interior of ellipsoid defined by
$$
\frac{x^2}{4}+y^2+z^2=1
$$
If we denote this domain by $S$. How can we calculate
$$
\int\int\int_S y^2dxdydz
$$

Comment: What do you think? What have you tried?

Comment: @ParclyTaxel I am unsure on how to get the limits, I tried spherical coordinates but got stuck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $x=2u$, $y=v$ and $z=w$. Then, 
$
u^2+v^2+w^2=1
$ and

$$
I=\int_S y^2dxdydz =2\int_{u^2+v^2+w^2<1}v^2dudvdw\\
$$

Due to symmetry,

$$
I=\frac23\int_{u^2+v^2+w^2<1}(u^2+v^2+w^2) dudvdw
= \frac{8\pi}3\int_0^1r^4dr=\frac{8\pi}{15}
$$

Answer (score 1):

One can calculate the following using Fubini's theorem writing the interior as:
$$V=\left\{\begin{array}{c}-1< z< 1 \\ -\sqrt{1-z^2}< y< \sqrt{1-z^2} \\ -2\sqrt{1-z^2-y^2}<x<2\sqrt{1-z^2-y^2}\end{array}\right\}$$
So that:
$$\iiint\limits_Vy^2{\rm d}x{\rm d}y{\rm d}z=\int\limits_{-1}^1\left[\int\limits_{-\sqrt{1-z^2}}^{\sqrt{1-z^2}}\left[\int\limits_{-2\sqrt{1-z^2-y^2}}^{\sqrt{1-z^2-y^2}}y^2{\rm d}x\right]{\rm d}y\right]{\rm d}z$$
Which is solvable. Another way is using the variation on Spherical coordinates:
$$
\left\{\begin{array}{ccl}x & = & 2r\cos{(\theta)}\sin{(\varphi)} \\ y & = & r\sin{(\theta)}\sin{(\varphi)} \\ z &= & r\cos{(\varphi)}\end{array}\right.
$$
With Jacobian being $2r^2\sin{(\varphi)}$ and domain in the new coordinates:
$$
\tilde{V}=\left\{\begin{array}{c}0<r<1 \\ 0<\theta<2\pi \\ 0<\varphi<\pi\end{array}\right\}
$$
So using Fubini again we get:
$$
\int\limits_0^1\left[\int\limits_0^{2\pi}\left[\int\limits_0^{\pi}\left(r^2\sin^2{(\theta)}\right)\left(2r^2\sin{(\varphi)}\right){\rm d}\varphi\right]{\rm d}\theta\right]{\rm d}r
$$
Which is much nicer in my opinion :)